# How to unify redundant tuples of a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
t = ({'x':1}, {'x':1}, {'y':2})
```

I am unifying it using:

```
l = []
for i in t:
     if i not in l:
        l.append(i)

tuple(l)
```

gives the result `({'x': 1}, {'y': 2})`

Is there any better way for that?

Another Sample Input = `({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2})`
Sample output: `({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2})`

Comment: what about `({'x':1}, {'x':2})`

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I updated my question with a sample Input/Output

Comment: Aha! See my newly updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: a completely different answer to the question as it was updated:

```
 dict([(x.items()[0], x) for x in t]).values()
```

This takes each dict and transforms it into a tuple. A tuple is hashable, so it can be used as the key in a dictionary. It then builds a `dict` with the hashed tuple as the key and the original `dict` as the value. This means the same dict is only stored once. We then take the values out of the `dict` as a `list`. And then build a `tuple`from that.

```
>>> t = ({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2})
>>> tuple(dict([(x.items()[0], x) for x in t]).values())
({'y': 1, 'x': 1}, {'x': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1})
```

Comment: This sequence should give:({'x':1},{'y':2}, {'y':3}, {'x':4, 'p':9})

Comment: the result should be tuple of dict. Not dict of distinct keys.

Comment: still not fullfill all cases.t = ({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':2, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2})  should return the same value. Because no two dictionary are same.You solution gives [{'x': 1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}].

Comment: @discky: on my system both `t = ({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2})` and `t = ({'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':3}, {'x':2, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2})` give the same result, namely `({'y': 1, 'x': 1}, {'x': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1})`.

Comment: @Joe, this could be simplified/optimized slightly with `tuple(dict((x.items()[0], x) for x in t).itervalues())`.

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner works:

```
dict([i.items()[0] for i in t])
```

Comment: Doesn't handle second example OP added where most of the dictionaries have more than one item. Regardless, in your answer the `[]` for generating an intermediate `list` are unnecessary since it's a generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think set may suit all u need. But a dict does not satisfy the requirement of member of  set--hashability, so we need a wrapper.

```
class HashableDictWrapper(object):
      def __init__(self, di):
          self.di = di
          self._hash_key = id("".join(["%s=%s" % (k, di[k]) for k in sorted(di.iterkeys())]))

      def __hash__(self):
          return self._hash_key

      def __eq__(self, other):
          return self.__hash__()==other.__hash__()

if __name__=="__main__":
      t = ({'x':1}, {'x':1}, {'y':2})
      s = set(map(HashableDictWrapper, t))
      tuple(map(lambda a:a.di, s))
```

UPDATED:
I make some modifications to @monkut 's answer:

```
t = ({'x':1}, {'x':1}, {'y':2})
p = map(lambda di:tuple((k,di[k]) for k in sorted(di.iterkeys())), t)
result = tuple(map(lambda x:dict(x), set(p)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may require a rethink of what you need, but sets are made for this.

```
>>> t = (("x",1), ("x",1), ("y", 2))
>>> set(t)
set([('x', 1), ('y', 2)])
```